# iOS: how to change the order of UITextField to be focused using IQKeyboardManager

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, iqkeyboardmanager

I have placed multiple `UITextFields` into an `UIViewController` in the storyboard.
I am using [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) to scroll the `UITextFields` over the keyboard when they are focused.

[image: IQKeyboardManager toolbar]

When I click the **next button** in the keyboard toolbar, another `UITextField` is getting focused while the current one loses focus.

How can I **control the order of the focus** of the `UITextField`s by the keyboard toolbar buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of research, I found that the focusing order of `UITextField`s depends on the order of the XML nodes in the storyboard file.

[image: The order of the XML nodes of <code>UITextField</code>s]

As a result I changed this order and everything works fine as I wanted.

Comment: for those who don't want to edit the raw xml, setting the order in storyboard or xib will also do

Answer (score 6):

Set `IQAutoToolbarManageBehaviour`

In your case could be

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().toolbarManageBehaviour = .byTag
```

Then add **tag** to your `TextFields`

```
textField1.tag = 1
textField2.tag = 2
textField3.tag = 3
```

Comment: Last version: IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarManageBehaviour = .byTag